# How does this particular use of MaybeT work?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to learn about monad transformers and I'm reading the [this page](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Monad_transformers) on the haskell wiki.

The code I'm confused about is the following:

```
isValid :: String -> Bool
isValid s = length s >= 5

getValidPassword :: MaybeT IO String
getValidPassword = do s <- lift getLine
                      guard (isValid s)
                      return s

askPassword :: MaybeT IO ()
askPassword = do lift $ putStrLn "Insert your new password:"
                 value <- getValidPassword
                 lift $ putStrLn "Storing in database..."
```

So far so good. I can run this and it works. But now, change `askPassword` to:

```
askPassword :: MaybeT IO ()
askPassword = do lift $ putStrLn "Insert your new password:"
                 value <- msum $ repeat getValidPassword
                 lift $ putStrLn "Storing in database..."
```

This will repeatedly wait for me to give a new input if it doesn't satisfy the valididity condition. I'm a bit lost how it does that. `repeat` repeats the action forever, and `msum` is just `foldr mplus mzero`, meaning it walks along the list and "adds" the values together.

Why doesn't this just return as soon as I give a bad input (the return value will be Nothing). I guess I'm not seeing where the logic for deciding when to stop and when to continue is embedded. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works because mplus for MaybeT is non-strict in its second argument:

```
mplus (return () :: MaybeT m ()) undefined
```

is equivalent to

```
return ()
```

This is a consequence of [the definition of mplus for MaybeT](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MaybeT-0.1.2/docs/src/Control-Monad-Maybe.html#line-53), which looks as follows:

```
instance (Monad m) => MonadPlus (MaybeT m) where
  mzero = MaybeT (return Nothing)
  mplus x y = MaybeT $ do v <- runMaybeT x
                          case v of
                            Nothing -> runMaybeT y
                            Just _  -> return v
```

As you can see, the second argument `y` of mplus is not executed unless the first argument `x` fails to return a result.

As a consequence of this, `msum` on the infinite list of actions obtained from `repeat getPassword` will only execute until the first one succeeds.

Answer (score 5):

Well, `msum` for `Maybe` is supposed to stop on the first SUCCESSFUL try, not the first failure.